# Как вывести строку на экран?

Tags: c, строки

Стоит задача написать программу, которая во введенной с клавиатуры строке считает и выводит количество символов '0'-'9' в ней содержащихся и еще выводит строку, в которой эти символы отсутствуют. (Выполняется все в отдельной функции). Символы я посчитал, а как сделать вывод строки без них, до меня не доходит.

```
#define DIM 10
void do_job(char* str, int *freq)
{
int i, len;
    for(i = 0; i < DIM; i++)
    *(freq + i) = 0;
len = strlen(str);
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
    if (*(str + i) >= '0'&&*(str + i) <= '9')
    (*(freq + (int)(*(str + i) - 48)))++;
}
```

Как можно сделать цикл, который "шагает" по строке и выбрасывает из неё цифры?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так

```
void do_job(char* str, int *freq)
{
    int i, offset;
    for (i=0; i < DIM; i++) freq[i] = 0;

    for (i = 0, offset = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (str[i] >= '0' && str [i] <= '9') {freq[str[i] - '0']++; offset++;}
        else str[i - offset] = str[i];      
    }
    str[i - offset] = '\0';
}
```